# Get selected value in appended select box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have created one select box for expense category and input box for expense amount and one button.

Now, when I select category and add amount than click on Add button then that value append to the another div but select box can not append with the above selected value.

Here I have write my code :

```js
var rowCount;
if (jQuery('#addedRows').children().length > 0) {
    var get_id = jQuery("#addedRows").children().last().attr('id');
    var last_char = get_id.substr(8);
    //alert(last_char);
    rowCount = last_char;
} else {
    rowCount = 0;
}

function addMoreRows(frm) {
    var cats = $(".exp_cat option:selected").text();
    var cats_id = $(".exp_cat option:selected").val();
    //alert(cats_id);
    var amnt = $('.exp_amnt').val();
    if (amnt == "") {
        alert("Add expense amount");
        return false
    } else {
        rowCount++;
        var recRow = '<p class="col-md-12" id="rowCount' + rowCount + '">';
        recRow += '<tr>';
        recRow += '<td>';

        $('.exp_c_' + rowCount).val(cats_id);

        recRow += '<select class="exp_c exp_c_' + rowCount + '" name="ana_acc[' + rowCount + '][acc_cat]">';

        recRow += '<option value="1">general cost</option><option value="2">it cost</option><option value="4">test</option>';

        recRow += '</select>';

        recRow += '</td>';
        recRow += '<td><input class="col-md-4 form-control" name="ana_acc[' + rowCount + '][exp_ammount]" value="' + amnt + '" type="text"  class="form-control"/></td>';
        recRow += '<td><a href="##" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeRow(' + rowCount + ')">Delete</a></td>';
        recRow += '</tr></p>';
        jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
    }
}

function removeRow(removeNum) {
    jQuery('#rowCount' + removeNum).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
    <div class="col-md-5 nopadding">
        <select id="invoice" class="exp_cat selectpicker auto-toggle toggled" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="exp_ana_cat">
         <option value="1">general cost</option>
         <option value="2">it cost</option>
         <option value="4">test</option> 
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 nopadding">
        <input class="form-control exp_amnt" type="text" name="exp_ana_amnt" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="##" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);" class="add_exp btn btn-primary">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="addedRows"></div>
```

As per the example, when you select `it cost` category than `it cost` category should be selected in appended data.

So what should I have to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean like this?

```js
var rowCount;
if (jQuery('#addedRows').children().length > 0) {
    var get_id = jQuery("#addedRows").children().last().attr('id');
    var last_char = get_id.substr(8);
    //alert(last_char);
    rowCount = last_char;
} else {
    rowCount = 0;
}

function addMoreRows(frm) {
    var cats = $(".exp_cat option:selected").text();
    var cats_id = $(".exp_cat option:selected").val();
    //alert(cats_id);
    var amnt = $('.exp_amnt').val();
    if (amnt == "") {
        alert("Add expense amount");
        return false
    } else {
        rowCount++;
        var recRow = '<p class="col-md-12" id="rowCount' + rowCount + '">';
        recRow += '<tr>';
        recRow += '<td>';

        $('.exp_c_' + rowCount).val(cats_id);

        recRow += '<select class="exp_c exp_c_' + rowCount + '" name="ana_acc[' + rowCount + '][acc_cat]">';

        recRow += '<option value="1">general cost</option><option value="2">it cost</option><option value="4">test</option>';

        recRow += '</select>';

        recRow += '</td>';
        recRow += '<td><input class="col-md-4 form-control" name="ana_acc[' + rowCount + '][exp_ammount]" value="' + amnt + '" type="text"  class="form-control"/></td>';
        recRow += '<td><a href="##" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeRow(' + rowCount + ')">Delete</a></td>';
        recRow += '</tr></p>';
        jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
    }
  
  $('select:last').val($('select:first').val())
}

function removeRow(removeNum) {
    jQuery('#rowCount' + removeNum).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
    <div class="col-md-5 nopadding">
        <select id="invoice" class="exp_cat selectpicker auto-toggle toggled" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" name="exp_ana_cat">
         <option value="1">general cost</option>
         <option value="2">it cost</option>
         <option value="4">test</option> 
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 nopadding">
        <input class="form-control exp_amnt" type="text" name="exp_ana_amnt" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="##" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);" class="add_exp btn btn-primary">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="addedRows"></div>
```

---

**EXPLAIN:**

I've add `$('select:last').val($('select:first').val())` on last line off `addMoreRows` function.

Answer (score 1):

Move the line:

```
$('.exp_c_' + rowCount).val(cats_id);
```

after

```
jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
```

This element does not exist until you append it so you cannot really do operations on it.

If you stick to the solution with select:first, select:last, make sure that there are no other select elements before and after the ones you have in your examples. Or switch to using class names with IDs as you do.